# How to get the same format for vim-prettier and vscode-prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, prettier, formatter

I have vim-prettier installed and also have the vscode extension for prettier installed.
They format differently however. I would like to use vim-prettier to format the same way I would for vscode's prettier.

I followed vscode's configuration and it lead me to /home/user/.prettierrc.json but it is empty and only has {} inside of it.

I put `let g:prettier#autoformat = ["/home/user/.prettierrc.json"]`
inside my .vimrc file but it does not format to the same way vscode-prettier does.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So first I tried `whereis prettier` and compared it to the value i get from running `:PrettierCliPath`

prettier is in /usr/local/bin/prettier
and the one that vim uses is in /home/user/node_modules/.bin/prettier

I tried to set my vimrc to point to the first one via
`let g:prettier#exec_cmd_path = "~/path/to/cli/prettier"`
But it didn't work. It gave me a syntax error whenever I tried to run prettier in vim.

After a long time I noticed this line in the README for vim-prettier
`Note: vim-prettier default settings differ from prettier intentionally. However they can be configured by:`
and it gave a bunch of settings like  `let g:prettier#config#print_width = 'auto'`

So I ended up just manually configuring each setting to the desired result.

Now I want to find a way to only allow these settings for a certain filetype(html) so that the formatter for html and css are different instead of the same.